# Injecting a service into angular controller unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to inject a service into my controllers unit test. I'm not looking to make a mock out of the service but just include it so that I can have access to all of its methods. Is this possible?

```
'use strict';

  describe('Offers : controller', function(){

    beforeEach(module('client'));

      var $scope,
          controller,
          $rootScope,
          genericService;


      beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $controller) {

        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        controller = $controller('OffersCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
        genericService = $injector.get('genericService');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

   }));

   it('should have a genericService', function () {
     expect(genericService.method).toBeDefined();
   });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just inject your own service the same way you did with the angular services:

```
var genericService;

beforeEach(inject(function(_genericService_) {
  genericService = _genericService_;
});
```

Note that you can use *underscores* around the argument name to avoid naming conflicts. Angular will strip those from the argument name when resolving the services to inject.